# Combobox showing Foreign Key not Reference Value

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, combobox

I have a table with a combination of Text Boxes and Comboboxes all bound to fields in a Users table.

The combo boxes are used to select items such as Location, Access rights and Title which are all listed in seperate tables.

However as the values for Location, Access rights and Title are stored in my users table as the integer Primary keys from the related tables this is what is being displayed on my form.

How do I set the combobox field to display the Loc_Name rather than the Loc_ID but still be bound to the original users table?

The second problem I have is that when I select the dropdown for the combo box I get the List of Locations (for example) which is fine and when I select the valid location it displays the Loc_Name in the combobox field. The problem here is that because the combobox is bound to an integer type field in the Users table the form will not accept the String Loc_Name only an integer value.

Am I going about this the wrong way????

Details of settings:

The Location combobox on my form is bound to the Location field in my users table which stores the foreign key integer value from the locations table.

The ComboBox datasource is set to the Locations Table Binding SOurce
The Combobox Display member is set to Loc_Name
The Combobox Value Member is set to Loc_ID
The Selected value is set to (None)

Comment: Looks like I might have been going about it the wrong way. Instead of referencing the valueID with the combo box I had to create a SELECT that join the two data tables and display the Joined data. On update the combobox had to be set to reference the original ID Field. Seeming like a very roundabout way of doing it. No where near as neat as Access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Should have put this here.

Looks like I might have been going about it the wrong way. Instead of referencing the valueID with the combo box I had to create a SELECT that join the two data tables and display the Joined data. On update the combobox had to be set to reference the original ID Field. Seeming like a very roundabout way of doing it. No where near as neat as Access.